# toggleClass/addClass doesn't work with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an input element:

```
<input id="box" type="text" />
```

And the following CSS class:

```
.box-change
{
    border-color:#ffffff;
}
```

As well as the following jQuery code:

```
$('#box').toggleClass('box-change');
```

However, it doesn't change the border color as I expect it to. Does anyone know why?

Edit:

The input already has a style, it is thus:

```
#box
{
border-color:#ff0000;
border-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-left-width:1px;
border-top-width:1px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you've set your border colour to white and maybe your background is white as well?

Comment: You say it doesn't change border colour *as you expect it to*... What are your exact expectations?

Comment: does it have a border to start with? changing `border-color` won't make any difference if there is no border to color. Otherwise it could be the cascade of the stylesheet. Have you used your browser inspector?

Comment: @Robert The background is not white, and I expect it to change the border color to white - I thought that was implied.

Comment: @ahren I have edited the OP to show the original style. It does originally contain a border.

Comment: @TheBoss - have you checked the cascade of the stylesheet? `#box` is more specific than `.box-change`, so probably overrides it.

Comment: @ahren That was the problem. Thank you! Would be good if I could state that your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your original styles are defined with `#box` it is more specific than `.box-change`, and by default overrides your new additions. It could also be that `.box-change` is higher up the cascade than `#box`.

You could solve it one of two ways:

```
#box.box-change{
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

or

```
.box-change{
  border-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've originally removed border, then you'll have to set

```
border-width
```

and

```
border-style
```

So in short your CSS should look like:

```
.box-change
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

But it all depends what your initial style is, what colour is background of the containing element of your input etc...

### Edit after you've provided more detail

your class doesn't get applied because class that sets style by ID has higher priority in cascade than CSS class. That's the main reason why you're not seeing it applied.

If you'd like your CSS class to *take over* you have two options:

1. set it as important:

   ```
   .box-change
   {
       border: 1px solid #fff !important;
   }
   ```
2. provide CSS rule that has higher specificity and will take over

   ```
   #box.box-change
   {
       border: 1px solid #fff;
   }
   ```

The second way is the preferred way, because using `!important` will make your CSS harder to maintain, since your classes don't cascade as per CSS but rather as per your importance. And you can easily loose control over that. **Avoid important unless on seldom occasions.**

### How to troubleshoot this?

To help you in the future, you should be using developer tools in browser (Chrome DevTools or Firebug for Firefox) that would immediately show you the problem. And of course understand [CSS specificity rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) and how they cascade.

Comment: I've already tried modifying the box-change class to include the border width and style attribute values as shown in the OP, however it didn't seem to make a difference. The problem persists.

Comment: @TheBoss: I edited my answer to provide information why it's not working.